# How to isolate test cases for ANTLR parser in Python?

Tags: python, testing, antlr4

I want to test my ANTLR parser with some test cases using Python and
the antlr v4 runtime. The problem that I ran into is about isolation
of test cases. In each test case, another file should be parsed. But
the parser (or the stream reader--I can't tell) seems to concatenate
the files that were read so far. So in test case n, the parsing result
is the concatenation of result of case n-1 and case n (and recursively
back until the first test case).

Here is a minimal working example:

File `Minimal.g4`:

```
grammar Minimal ;

WS : [ \t\n\r\f] ;

WORD : (~ ([ \n\r\t\f]) )+ ;

text : ( token | WS+ )* ;

token : WORD ;
```

File `minimal/minimal.py`:

```
from antlr4 import *
from minimal.MinimalListener import MinimalListener

class MinimalListListener(MinimalListener):

    tokens = []

    def exitToken(self, ctx):
        self.tokens.append(ctx.WORD().getText())
```

File `test_minimal.py`:

```
import unittest
import os
from antlr4 import *
from minimal.MinimalListener import MinimalListener
from minimal.MinimalLexer import MinimalLexer
from minimal.MinimalParser import MinimalParser

from minimal.minimal import MinimalListListener


class MinimalTstBase(unittest.TestCase):

    fname = None
    
    def setUp(self):
        self.parsed = []
        input_stream = FileStream(os.path.join("samples", self.fname), encoding="utf-8")
        lexer = MinimalLexer(input_stream)
        stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
        parser = MinimalParser(stream)
        tree = parser.text()    # start rule
        printer = MinimalListListener()
        walker = ParseTreeWalker()
        walker.walk(printer, tree)
        self.parsed = printer.tokens # get result stored in the listener

    def tearDown(self):
        self.parsed = []
        
class TestCite1(MinimalTstBase):

    fname = "cite1.txt"

    def test_parsed(self):
        self.assertEqual(
            self.parsed,
            ["A", "B"])

class TestCite2(MinimalTstBase):

    fname = "cite2.txt"

    def test_parsed(self):
        self.assertEqual(
            self.parsed,
            ['c', 'd'])
```

File `samples/cite1.txt`:

```
A B
```

File `samples/cite2.txt`:

```
 c d
```

File `minimal/__init__.py` is just an empty file.
File `setup.py` is just boilerplate:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name = "minimal-antlr-testing-example",
    version = "0.0.1",
    description = "Minimal testing example",
    classifiers = [
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    packages = find_packages(where="."),
    python_requires = ">=3.6",
    install_requires = [
        "wheel",
        "setuptools",
        "antlr4-python3-runtime==4.9.1"
        ],
    test_suite = 'minimal',
    )
```

File `requirements.txt`:

```
wheel==0.36.2
antlr4-python3-runtime==4.9.1
```

After running

```
java -cp antlr-4.9.1-complete.jar org.antlr.v4.Tool -o minimal/ \
-Xexact-output-dir -Dlanguage="Python3" Minimal.g4
```

there are the following files:

```
./minimal/Minimal.tokens
./minimal/MinimalListener.py
./minimal/MinimalParser.py
./minimal/Minimal.interp
./minimal/MinimalLexer.tokens
./minimal/MinimalLexer.py
./minimal/MinimalLexer.interp
./minimal/test_minimal.py
./minimal/minimal.py
./minimal/__init__.py
./samples/cite2.txt
./samples/cite1.txt
./Minimal.g4
./requirements.txt
./setup.py
```

Installing and running the tests:

```
python3 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
python setup.py bdist_wheel
python setup.py test

...

test_parsed (minimal.test_minimal.TestCite1) ... ok
test_parsed (minimal.test_minimal.TestCite2) ... FAIL

======================================================================
FAIL: test_parsed (minimal.test_minimal.TestCite2)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/clueck/src/minimal/antlr/minimal/test_minimal.py", line 46, in test_parsed
    ['c', 'd'])
AssertionError: Lists differ: ['A', 'B', 'c', 'd'] != ['c', 'd']

First differing element 0:
'A'
'c'

First list contains 2 additional elements.
First extra element 2:
'c'

- ['A', 'B', 'c', 'd']
+ ['c', 'd']
```

How can I isolate the parser runs when running unit tests?

Kind regards

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. If `printer.predecessors` contains leftovers from the previous run, then I would imagine the problem to be in the definition of `NumPredListListener` class (but of course I don't know that for a fact, so you should make sure to post enough code so that it can be run and reproduces the issue, which ensures that whichever part of the code is causing the problem is guaranteed to be included).

Comment: @sepp2k : You're right. I replaced my app's code with a minimal reproducible example. Still the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MinimalListListener(MinimalListener):

    tokens = []
```

This creates a single list belonging to the `MinimalListListener` class, which is shared between all instances of that class. So if you create two instances of the class, which both add elements to the list, the list will end up containing elements from both of those instances.

To create variables specific to each instance in Python, you set the variable inside `__init__`, not the class body:

```
class MinimalListListener(MinimalListener):
    def __init__(self):
        self.tokens = []
```

Comment: Yes! This solved my problem. So I missed the difference between class attributes and instance attributes here. Now, that I have fixed my listener, all works as expected. Thank you very much!